# I tried to open an image using pillow module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image

image1 = Image.open('img1.jpg', "rb")
image1.show()
```

using this command

I got the following error, I tried to open with open modes like rb but it raised a value error of bad mode

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gowtham\Desktop\Quarantine python\Image manipulation\img.py", line 3, in <module>
    image1 = Image.open('img1.jpg',"rb")
  File "C:\Users\Gowtham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2599, in open
    raise ValueError("bad mode %r" % mode)
ValueError: bad mode 'rb'
[Finished in 1.047s]
```

Comment: The docs state that the `Image.open()` method only takes an option of `'r'` for the `mode` argument. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [[ReadTheDocs.Pillow]: PIL.Image.open(fp, mode='r')](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> - **mode** – The mode. ***If given, this argument must be “r”***.

Probably, this argument is kept for backwards compatibility only (or to be consistent with other *open* like functions).

Change (the line of) your code to:

```py
image1 = Image.open("img1.jpg")
```